# XSLT 'key' applying expression in 'use'

Tags: xml, xslt, key, substring

I have an XML fragment

```
    <node>
            <abc>part_1</abc>
    </node>
    <node>
            <abc>part_2</abc>
    </node>
```

How can I ignore the string `"part_"` and specify in the `use` attribute of `xsl:key` only integer part? Specifically, I need help in using `<key>`'s `use` attribute.

I tried following:

`<key name="uniq-abc" match='abc' use='substring-after(., '_')/>`

but it's not working.

Following is the source XML:

```
    <ppp.PppControlProtocol>
        <shelfId>1</shelfId>
        <snmpPortId>841023490</snmpPortId>
        <controlProtocolType>lCp</controlProtocolType>
        <state>initial</state>
        <lastClearedTime>0</lastClearedTime>
        <restartCount>0</restartCount>
        <deploymentState>0</deploymentState>
        <objectFullName>network:138.120.242.60:ppp:interface-9/1/2.sts12_1:cp-Link</objectFullName>
        <name>cp-Link</name>
    </ppp.PppControlProtocol>
```

And I want to use following value and extract IP part `138.120.242.60`

```
    <objectFullName>network:138.120.242.60:ppp:interface-9/1/2.sts12_1:cp-Link</objectFullName>
```

And here is the part of the XSLT that is trying to extract it.

```
    <xsl:key name="uniq-ips" match="objectFullName" use="substring-before(substring-after(., ':'), ':')"/>
```

Here is how I'm using the key:

```
    <xsl:apply-templates select="ppp.PppControlProtocol/objectFullName[generate-id() = generate-id(key('uniq-ips', .)[1])]"/>
    .
    .
    .
    <xsl:for-each select="key('uniq-ips', $currentIP)">
```

Comment: Can you give a complete example of what is not working (complete XML  and XSLT)? Your markup for `<key>` is flawed, and of course you can't use a key without giving it a name. You might also be doing something wrong when using the `key()` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**There is a problem here**:

> ```
> <xsl:apply-templates select=
>   "ppp.PppControlProtocol/objectFullName
>                 [generate-id() 
>                = 
>                  generate-id(key('uniq-ips', .)[1])
>                 ]"/>
> ```

**Because the key named `'uniq-ips'` is defined in this way:**

```
    <xsl:key name="uniq-ips" match="objectFullName" 
             use="substring-before(substring-after(., ':'), ':')"/>
```

**you need to correct the code above to:**

```
 <xsl:apply-templates select=
   "ppp.PppControlProtocol/objectFullName
                 [generate-id() 
                = 
                  generate-id(key('uniq-ips', 
                                  substring-before(substring-after(., ':'), ':')
                                  )[1]
                             )
                 ]"/>
```

Comment: It weird that for using the key you have to repeat what you define in the key. So what the point of creating a key?

Comment: @Guasqueño, By defining the key, one gives the **function** which gives us the values that identify each of the nodes that this key is for. But in the `key()` function one must provide the actual value. Any actual value is just that, just a possible value of the function, that is provided in `<xsl:key match="..." use = '{some-function-expression}' />` Using an `<xsl:key.../>` is analogous to defining a hash-table (Dictionary) with keys that identify nodes. You can watch a good Pluralsight course to learn more: https://app.pluralsight.com/library/courses/xslt-foundations-part1/table-of-contents

Answer (score 0):

The following should suffice:

```
<xsl:key name="k1" match="abc" use="substring-after(., '_')"/>
```

(where of course the complete stylesheet needs a namespace declaration of `xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"`).

If you still have problems then I agree with Thomas, show us details of XML input, XSLT code, XSLT processor used, exact error message you get.